# fetchsize in resultset set to 0 by default

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have to query a database and result set is very big. I am using `MySQL` as data base. To avoid the "OutOfMemoryError" after a lot of search I got two options: One using `LIMIT`(specific to database) and other is using `jdbc` fetchSize attribute.

I have tested the option 1(`LIMIT`) an it is working but it is not the desired solution. I do not want to do it.

Using `jdbc` I found out that `ResultSet` size is set to 0 by default. How can I change this to some other value. I tried the following:

a) First Try:

```
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
rs.setFetchSize(1000);  //Not possible as exception occurs before.
```

b) Second T Even if this is not there then also I need to communicate to databse multiple timry:

```
rs.setFetchSize(1000);  //Null pointer exception(rs is null).
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

c) Third Try:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.createStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setFetchSize(1000);
```

None of this is working. Any help appreciated!

**Edit:**

I do not want a solution using limit because:
a) I have millions of rows in my result set. Now doing multiple query is slow. My assumption is that database takes multiple queries like

```
SELECT *  FROM a LIMIT 0, 1000
SELECT *  FROM a LIMIT 1000, 2000
```

as two different queries.

b) The code is looks messy because you need to have additional counters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MySQL JDBC driver always fetches all rows, unless the fetch size is set to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

See the [MySQL Connector/J JDBC API Implementation Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory.
>   In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate, and due to
>   the design of the MySQL network protocol is easier to implement. If
>   you are working with ResultSets that have a large number of rows or
>   large values, and cannot allocate heap space in your JVM for the
>   memory required, you can tell the driver to stream the results back
>   one row at a time.
>
> To enable this functionality, create a Statement instance in the
>   following manner:
>
> ```
> stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
>               java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
> stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
> ```
>
> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch
>   size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream
>   result sets row-by-row. After this, any result sets created with the
>   statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

Comment: Can't we retrieve in chunks rather than row by row?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Not in the MySQL JDBC driver, that implementation is either everything, or one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all you should change your query like

```
SELECT * FROM RandomStones LIMIT 1000;
```

Or

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(qry);
stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

> To set the fetch size for a query, call [`setFetchSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm) on the statement object prior to executing the query. If you set the fetch size to N, then N rows are fetched with each trip to the database.

Comment: it is working. Thats's what I have written in question. But I do not want that

Answer (score 0):

In [MySQL connector-j 5.1 implementation notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html), they said there are 2 ways to handle this situation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btDrY.png)

The 1st is to make the statement retrieve data row by row, the 2nd can support batch retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mysql performance enhancement documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-performance-extensions.html#cj-conn-prop_useCursorFetch) we must set `useCursorFetch` connection property to `true`. Only then, `setFetchSize` will work on statement object. For example, look at the code snipped below.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance());

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", "USERNAME");
properties.setProperty("password", "PASSWORD");
properties.setProperty("useCursorFetch", "true");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, properties);

Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
statement.setFetchSize(100);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY);

System.out.println("Fetch size in resultSet: " + resultSet.getFetchSize());
```