# How is limit clause implemented MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a very big table to retrieve records from. I am using MySQL. To avoid out of memory exception we need to have retrieve results wither one by one using JDBC or use `limit` clause in query.

So to retrieve complete result set we have to do the following:

```
select * from employee limit 0,1000;  //query 1
select * from employee limit 1000,2000;  //query 2
select * from employee limit 2000,3000;  //query 3
… and so on.
```

How are these queries executed internally(different or one).

Additional Question: 
What will be the performance in comparison to using JDBC to retrieve one by one(see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496616/fetchsize-in-resultset-set-to-0-by-default/20496877?noredirect=1#comment30640936_20496877))

Comment: @to whoever voted to close: Why is it too broad. It is as specific as it can get.

Comment: I am surprised this makes any difference.  You will be retrieving one result at a time in batches.  Placing a limit allows you to "page" the data coming to you but most likely the same memory will be used in the end.  If you where clause takes a long time, I would make sure the fields used are indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to figure out is how to scan through all the rows of a very large table in batches.  Limit is probably not the best way to do this.  I recommend using an index to filter the rows; ideally this would be the primary key.  Suppose you have an integer primary key; you would do something like:

```
select * from employee limit 1000; // query 1
// in your client, record the max. primarry key value in the batch, call that "maxid"
select * from employee where id > maxid limit 1000; // query 2
// again, record the maxid (id of the last row) and repeat until no rows are returned
```

This will generally perform best.  In some cases the database may be able to optimize limit to do the same kind of thing, but I have found that it often does not.   YMMV and you should measure performance to be sure, but the approach  I advocate here is pretty much guaranteed to work no matter how weird the database query optimizer is.

Comment: Nice thought!
But I cannot apply this. For some weird reason the any where clause takes very very long for answer. We are trying to avoid it and do aggregation on our local system rather than on server.

Comment: Do you have an index?  If your server cannot execute simple queries using a primary key, there is no hope of getting decent performance no matter what you do.