# how to setFetchSize on a cursor

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

How to set fetch size on a cursor returned by stored procedure. Please find my below code snippet:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
cstmt = (CallableStatement) conn.createStatement();
cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
cstmt.execute();
rst = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(sqlQuery);
rst.setFetchSize(100);
```

but resultset seems to ignore setFetchSize. Can anyone suggest me solution? also my oracle version is ojdbc11.2.0

Comment: Which driver are you using? Like mysql, oracle. May be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496616/fetchsize-in-resultset-set-to-0-by-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `autocommit` as false,

```
conObj.setAutoCommit(false);
```

And load the `callable` statement, `CallableStatement cstmt = connObj.createStatement();`

From Docs,

> In the case of statements returning a ResultSet, the statement
>   completes when the last row of the ResultSet has been retrieved or
>   when the ResultSet has been closed. In more complex cases, a single
>   statement can return multiple results as well as output parameter
>   values. Here, the COMMIT occurs when all results and output parameter
>   values have been retrieved.

Comment: Can you provide complete syntax

Comment: You can simply add the code after declaring the connection object .

Comment: No Krish, does not seem to work. I have edited my code as above

Comment: where do you call stored proc when you load Callable Statement using create object?

Comment: Answering my own question. This feature is not available along with oracle driver. Although the api to setfetchSize() is available on callable statement and resultset oracle driver just igonres the size which is set and fetches default number of rows as declared by oracle driver